# How can I use data passed into jade template in the views javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Rendering Data into template `res.render('account/pets/allPets', { petMap, title: 'All Pets' })`
I have tried two thing to make this work

A)

```
        var neighborhoods = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < petMap.length; i++) {
         neighborhoods.push(new google.maps.LatLng(petMap[i].location.loc[0],pet.location.loc[1]))
        }
```

B)

```
    var neighborhoods = [
    each pet in petMap
      new google.maps.LatLng(petMap[i].location.loc[0],pet.location.loc[1])
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `patMap` is a javascript object, you are required to do a few hacky things to make this work. Pug renders serverside, while javascript on the client, so you cannot directly access a pug variable in JS. What you **CAN** do is convert your js object into a string when the pug compiles, then parse it to JSON when the client executes.

```
var petMap = JSON.parse(("#{JSON.stringify(petMap)}").replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
/*
    Let me break this down in terms of execution
    "#{JSON.stringify(petMap)}" -> executes server side, converts #{} accesses pug variable petMap, which has been converted to an object
    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"') -> replaces quote escape sequences (something html does for security) back to quotes so JSON can be parsed
    JSON.parse -> parses json from stringified json the server sent to the client
*/
```

Comment: I stumbled upon that answer and it looked hacky and a bit messy so I ended up adding data attributes to my list items then i was able to place them on a map and add filters from there. work well for me `li.in(data-location=pet.location.loc, data-address=pet.location.name, data-name=pet.name, data-img=pet.picture, data-id=pet._id)` thank you for your response and the good explanation.